# snmp private mib prevent node being readable for public user

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I am dealing with a private mib which includes some nodes with sensitive information.
I want these node to only be readable by a user who has a private community string.

details:

```
usersEntry
    usersIndex
    usersName
    usersPassword
```

I want this sensitive information readable only for users with a community string and not
for users with a private community string.

Comment: yes,i forgot somthing,  the snmp version is SNMPv2c.  platform: Linux

Comment: Are you implementing an SNMP agent?

Comment: Your description is self-conflicting, so please fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are writing an SNMP agent of your own, the flexibility on security depends on the vendor of that agent. Talk to the vendor and you will know the answer.

Generally speaking, for SNMP v2 you won't get what you want, as role based security model was introduced only in SNMP v3,

http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3414.txt

If the vendor happens to also back port RFC3414 support for v2, you should be lucky enough to also use it in v2. If not, you are on your own.